# Determine the path that created by a sector of circle

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

[image]

ABC circle sector turns on ground (x axis) as shown in the figure. A is the center of the circle. $\angle{OAB}=\angle{OAC}=\alpha $

$|AB|=r$

$\cfrac{|AP|}{|PC|}=k$

The corners meet on point $H$ in the limit points. What is the curve equation $f(x)$ that passing from $P',P,P''$ 
Thanks for answers

Comment: How is it moving? You may look for the *cycloid curve*.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid

Comment: @Berci Thanks for the link.It is similiar to Cycloid but turning point in circle in my question, not on circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a curtate cycloid.  Refer to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CurtateCycloid.html